# flutter dart: The argument type 'void Function(int)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'dynamic Function(dynamic)'

Tags: flutter, dart

here are my codes:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './quiz.dart';
import './result.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    //TODo implement creatState
    return _MyAppState();
  }
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final _questions = const [
    {
      'questionText': 'what\'s your favorite color?',
      'answers': [
        {'text': 'Black', 'score': 10},
        {'text': 'Red', 'score': 5},
        {'text': 'Green', 'score': 3},
        {'text': 'White', 'score': 1},
      ]
    },
    {
      'questionText': 'what\'s your favorite animal?',
      'answers': [
        {'text': 'Lion', 'score': 10},
        {'text': 'Tiger', 'score': 5},
        {'text': 'Elephant', 'score': 3},
        {'text': 'cat', 'score': 1},
      ]
    },
    {
      'questionText': 'what\'s your favorite instructor?',
      'answers': [
        {'text': 'Tooraj', 'score': 10},
        {'text': 'Behzad', 'score': 5},
        {'text': 'Behnaz', 'score': 3},
        {'text': 'Iraj', 'score': 1},
      ]
    },
  ];
  var _questionIndex = 0;
  var _totalScore = 0;

  void _resetQuiz() {
    setState(() {
      _questionIndex = 0;
      _totalScore = 0;
    });
  }

  void _answerQuestion(int score) {
    _totalScore += score;

    setState(() {
      _questionIndex = _questionIndex + 1;
    });
    if (_questionIndex < _questions.length) {
      print('we have more questions!');
    } else {
      print('no more questions!');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('my first app'),
        ),
        body: _questionIndex < _questions.length
            ? Quiz(
                answerQuestion: _answerQuestion,
                questionIndex: _questionIndex,
                questions: _questions,
              )
            : Result(_totalScore, _resetQuiz),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

an error is here:

```
answerQuestion: _answerQuestion,
```

please help me out.

how can I assign a function to a parameter?

The argument type 'void Function(int)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'dynamic Function(dynamic)'.dartargument_type_not_assignable

void _answerQuestion(int score)

*package:my_app/main.dart*

The argument type 'void Function(int)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'dynamic Function(dynamic)'.dart[argument_type_not_assignable](https://dart.dev/diagnostics/argument_type_not_assignable)

void _answerQuestion(int score)

*package:my_app/main.dart*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're encountering is because the `answerQuestion` parameter in your Quiz widget is expecting a function with the type `dynamic Function(dynamic)`, but you're trying to assign `_answerQuestion`, which is of type `void Function(int)`.

You can solve it with two ways:

1. You change the type of your answerQuestion parameter as your function `_answerQuestion` type which is void Function(int) which is the best way, so..

   ```
   class Quiz extends StatelessWidget {
     const Quiz({super.key, required this.answerQuestion});

     final void Function(int) answerQuestion;
     /// Your other parameters..

     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return const Placeholder();
     }
   }
   ```
2. you call the function manually, but i don't suggest that as you're sending a dynamic value from the `Quiz` widget, which will make type mismatch errors. I total don't recommend it but for reference...

   ```
   Quiz(
       answerQuestion: (v) => _answerQuestion(v),
       /// Your Other Parameter..
    );
   ```